# middleman init my_project_name not working ,

Tags: middleman

here is the stack trace,

/Users/hadronsolutions/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require': cannot load such file -- middleman-core/cli (LoadError)
    from /Users/hadronsolutions/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in`rescue in require'
    from /Users/hadronsolutions/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /Users/hadronsolutions/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/middleman-core-3.3.6/bin/middleman:12:in`'
    from /Users/hadronsolutions/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/middleman:23:in `load'
    from /Users/hadronsolutions/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/middleman:23:in`'
    from /Users/hadronsolutions/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/hadronsolutions/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`'

Comment: Please provide some more information, when does this happen, what code do you have? "Not working" is not useful information

Comment: gem install middleman was installed and working fine even i create project using middleman init command but when i tried to use middleman-blog then this error comes. now i am not able to create simple project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a typical problem for Middleman v3, addressed in Middleman v4 (not yet released as of Sep 2014).

To resolve it, do the following:

1. Create an empty project folder.
2. Create a `Gemfile` in that folder with the following content:

   ```
   source 'https://rubygems.org/'

   gem 'middleman', '~> 3.3.6'
   ```

   Notes:

   - For the up to date `gem ...` line visit https://rubygems.org/gems/middleman .
   - Don't try to add more gems in the `Gemfile`, the file will be overwritten.
3. Run the following commands in that folder:

   ```
   bundle
   bundle exec middleman init .
   ```
4. You're all set up. Don't forget to prepend CLI commands with `bundle exec`.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the `bundle exec` route but eventually fixed it more simply with `gem install middleman-cli && gem install middleman core`...